# postgres json output for 1:n tables

Tags: json, postgresql

So I have a problem I can't seem to figure out. I have to make a fuction(in postgres, also called a stored procedure). The function has to check if a given id is a certain 'thing' for example:

Given id 10, is has the check if the id is a human(another table) or a animal(another table). If it is one of the two, it has to get all the attributes of that tabel. This repsonse has to be json formatted so that the application builder can build an extjs application around it.

So can someone give a push in the right direction, do I need to have a json out parameter? or a character varying? How do I give something back based on whenever the table exists or not. I hope someone can give me a push. Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you're needing to send in the response? Sounds like you just need to represent an object in JSON. The object properties would describe the table.

Comment: For example: if i want to know if a certain id is a person or a animal, i would go like this: {Person:{id=>1,name=>2}} if a id is a animal and a person it would be like this: {Person:{id=>1, name=>2}, Animal:{id=>1, name= 2}} The json that does come back has to be in a treeview in extjs